# Paypal gateway returns error for Magento store

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment-gateway

I have set up Paypal Payments Pro on Magento 1.7.0.2, but when I try to place an order, Paypal returns an error:

```
[response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-05-05T15:52:41Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 310e857075603
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 10850615
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security error
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security header is not valid
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )
```

I have checked my credentials here, and they are returning a success. 
https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?&user=xxxxxxxxxx&pwd=xxxxxxxxxx&signature=xxxxxxxxxx&version=70.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&CANCELURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=50&CURRENCYCODE=USD

Any ideas about what could cause this security header issue?

Answer (score 2):

generally this error means you are not using the correct API credentials. If you are convinced your credentials are correct then take a look at your endpoint. Sandbox credentials will not be valid in the production environment and live credentials will produce this error in the sandbox

Comment: How can I double check my endpoint? I have the setting 'Sandbox Mode' in Magento set to 'No', and I have checked the Paypal URL where I am copying the credentials from, and it is not the sandbox url.